# Constructor issue <Unable to read memory>

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I have to create a class Histogram and make operations on this class. The input can be one dimensional array  or a two dimensional array. The problem appears when i convert the array into a matrix. This what i have tried so far. The error is `<Unable to read memory>`

histrogram.h

```
#ifndef HISTOGRAM_H
#define HISTOGRAM_H
#include<iostream>
class Histogram
{
private:
    int** matrix;
    int lines;
    void SortMatrix();
public:
    Histogram(){ }
    Histogram(int elements[], int elementsNr);
    Histogram(int** m, int l);
    void Print();
};
#endif
```

historgram.cpp

```
#include"histogram.h"
using namespace std;
Histogram::Histogram(int** m, int l)
{
    matrix=m;
    lines=l;
    SortMatrix();
}

Histogram::Histogram(int elements[], int elementsNr)
{
    lines=0;
    //initialize matrix : elementrNr lines and 2 columns
    int** matrix=new int*[elementsNr];
    for(int i=0;i<elementsNr;i++)
    {
        matrix[i]=new int[2];
        matrix[i][0]=INT_MIN;
        matrix[i][1]=INT_MIN;
    }
    //search each element from the array in the matrix
    bool found=false;
    for(int i=0;i<elementsNr;i++)
    {
        found=false;
        for(int j=0;j<elementsNr;j++)
        {
            //the element was found in the matrix ( on the first column )
            if(matrix[j][0] == elements[i])
            {
                matrix[j][1]++;
                found=true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(!found)
        {
            matrix[lines][0]=elements[i];
            matrix[lines][1]=1;
            lines++;
        }
    }
    SortMatrix();
}
void Histogram::SortMatrix()
{
    bool flag=true;
    int temp;
    for(int i=0;(i<lines) && flag;i++)
    {
        flag=false;
        if(matrix[i+1][0]>matrix[i][0])
        {
            temp=matrix[i][0];
            matrix[i][0]=matrix[i+1][0];
            matrix[i+1][0]=temp;
            flag=true;
        }
    }
}
void Histogram::Print()
{

    for(int i=0;i<lines;i++)
    {
        cout<<matrix[i][0]<<" : " <<matrix[i][1]<<endl;
    }

}
```

main.cpp

```
#include"histogram.h"
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int arr[]={6,7,3,1,3,2,4,4,7,5,1,1,5,6,6,4,5};
    Histogram h(arr,17);
    h.Print();
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here

```
int** matrix=new int*[elementsNr];
```

replace with

```
matrix=new int*[elementsNr];
```

because`matrix` is already a member variable. You are creating a new temporary variable double pointer named `matrix` and allocating memory to it rather than your member variable `matrix`

Answer (score 3):

A couple of people have already given you advice about how to fix some of the problems with this code. I'll give slightly different advice that may initially seem a bit brutal by comparison, but I'll try to demonstrate how it's honestly useful rather than nasty.

I would throw out your existing code with the possible exception of what you have in `main`, and start over, using an `std::map`. What you're doing right now is basically trying to re-create the capabilities that `std::map` already provides (and even when your code is fixed, it's not doing the job as well as `std::map` does right out of the box).

Using map, your *whole* program comes out to something like this:

```
std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, std::pair<int, int> const &d) { 
    return os << d.first << " : " << d.second;
}

int main() { 
    std::map<int, int> h;

    for (int i=0; i<17; i++)
        ++h[arr[i]];

    std::copy(h.begin(), h.end(), 
              std::ostream_iterator<std::pair<int, int> >(std::cout, "\n"));
    return 0;
}
```

If you want to maintain virtually the same interface as your `histogram` class provided, it's pretty easy to do that -- the `for` loop goes into the constructor, the `copy` into `print` (and `SortMatrix` disappears, because a `map` is always sorted).

By doing this, you change from an O(N<sup>2</sup>) algorithm to an O(N log N) algorithm. The bugs others have pointed out disappear completely, because the code that contained them is no longer needed. The only real disadvantage I can see is that the result *will* probably use a bit more memory -- it uses a balanced tree with individually allocated nodes, which is likely to introduce a fair amount of overhead for nodes that only contain 2 `int`s (and a bit for balancing). I can't quite imagine worrying about this though -- long before you have enough nodes for the memory usage to become significant, you have *way* too many to present to even consider presenting to the user.

Comment: +1 excellent advice. Concerning memory, one advantage is that no space is used for empty bins.

Comment: Excellent advice to a programmer in a professional setting. Not necessarily so good for someone learning to program.

Answer (score 0):

@mathematician1975 already provided an answer for the main problem. There's another bug in `SortMatrix()`: you only swap the elements of the first column, therefore after sorting, the counts (in the second column) will not be correct anymore. You'll have to insert

```
temp=matrix[i][1];
matrix[i][1]=matrix[i+1][1];
matrix[i+1][1]=temp;
```

to get it working.